# Error error: cannot find symbol class AuthCredential

Tags: android, gradle, firebase-authentication

After I delete the library dependency file of Firebase database library because of error "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/LICENSE'"
so I added configure file it compiles but it shows another error
it didn't compile so I tried to add the library dependency of firebase real-time database but it doesn't found symbol class

**Gradle File**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.one4all.Sumo"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.3.5"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst  'META-INF/*'
    }






}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.2.2'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    //Admin
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.10.0'


    //firebase Admin
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.10.0'
//    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
//    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
//    implementation "com.xwray:groupie:2.5.1"
//    implementation "com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.5.1"

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()


}
```

**java file**

```
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;//master branch



public class SignInWithGoogle extends BaseActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "GoogleActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    // [END declare_auth]

    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private TextView mStatusTextView;
    private TextView mDetailTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in_with_google);
        ;


        // Views
        mStatusTextView = findViewById(R.id.status);
        mDetailTextView = findViewById(R.id.detail);

        // Button listeners
        findViewById(R.id.signInButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.signOutButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.disconnectButton).setOnClickListener(this);

        // [START config_signin]
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.client))//if not works default_web_client_id
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // [END config_signin]

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        // [START initialize_auth]
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // [END initialize_auth]
    }

    // [START on_start_check_user]
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if userListFragment is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(currentUser);
    }
    // [END on_start_check_user]

    // [START onactivityresult]
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
                Log.i("loging","login succeful");
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.i("loging","login was notsucceful");
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                Toast.makeText(SignInWithGoogle.this,"sign in was not succeful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(null);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        }
    }
    // [END onactivityresult]

    // [START auth_with_google]
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        showProgressDialog();
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in userListFragment's information
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignInWithGoogle.this,MainChatActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the userListFragment.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_layout), "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
```

**Register Activity**

```
public void createFireBaseUser(){
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Log.d("sumo","sumo created");

                if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                    showErrorDialog("Email already exists");
                }else {
                    saveName();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

**Error**

> error: cannot find symbol variable GoogleAuthProvider
>
> error: cannot find symbol class AuthResult
>
> error: cannot find symbol class AuthResult
>
> error: cannot find symbol class FirebaseUser
>
> error: cannot find symbol class AuthCredential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem first I tried to remove all the dependency that caused the problem then I clean the project after that  I rebuild the project then import the dependency. Hope this helps.